# what register@number means in ida pro

Tags: disassembly, ida

I'm new to Hex-ray. While studying deep inside each functions, I arouse one question that can't find answer through googling or searching. In ida generated comment in function Pseudocode mode(F5), 
It says like this:

```
char __userpurge function@<al>(int a1, ... )
{
  HANDLE v2;  // eax@1
  DWORD v3;  // eax@4
  void *4; // eax@6
  LARGE_INTEGER FileSize; // [esp+4h] [ebp-8h]@2
}
```

Can anyone tell me the meaning about `eax@1`, `eax@4` these kind of stuffs?
In addition to that, I'm also wonder what `[esp+4h] [ebp-8h]@2` means.

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/4118

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered in [Igor Skochinsky's answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/information-provided-by-hex-rays-after-symbol-in-variable-declarations) on Stack Exchange Reverse Engineering:

> The numbers denote the basic block number in the microcode where the
>   variable was first used. Microcode basic blocks do not necessarily
>   match the basics block in the disassembly, because during optimization
>   steps the microcode basic blocks may be split, merged, added, or
>   removed.
>
> You can see some samples of microcode in Ilfak's [whitepaper on the
>   decompiler](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/ppt/decompilers_and_beyond_white_paper.pdf)
>   or in some of the old blog posts:
>   [1](http://www.datarescue.com/laboratory/vd.htm)
>   [2](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=39) (block number is the first number on
>   the line).

It is recommended to ask questions about reverse engineering in [SE.RE](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) community.